# How to map data from an array of objects for an options selector product in react?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, variant

- I'm simply trying to map data from an API with the intention of creating options to select for a product.
- I am able to do it as long as the API data for the specific concept (for example bluetooth, color, weight) has a simple array format as:
  `"bluetooth":["4.0","A2DP","LE"]`
  Then using the following code renders the options to choose on the selector

  ```
          <OptionsCss onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}>
          {product.bluetooth?.map((s) => (
            <FieldCss key={s}>{s}</FieldCss>
          ))}
  ```
- However with a concept named storage I'm unable to get the values on the product options to choose. Here the array structure is as follows :

  `"storages":[{"code":2000,"name":"16 GB"},{"code":2001,"name":"32 GB"}]`

  Here I just need the values as for example 16GB and 32GB. So mapping the api following the previous way gives me empty choice options.
- Then the **question would be**, How can I get access to the name values from the example mentioned
  previously ? and what should I change from the previous mapping example?

Answer (score 0):

When you map through the array, you get one object at a time then you can access the property you want from the object using `storage.name`.

```js
obj.storages.map(storage => storage.name)
```

So in the case of your component you'd have

```js
 <OptionsCss onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)}>
        {product.storages?.map((s) => (
          <FieldCss key={s.name}>{s.name}</FieldCss>
        ))}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it really makes sense. Unfortunately I'm still unable to retrieve the storage name values for the choice selector

Comment: hmm, are you sure of what the API returns, and also is the name `product`?